# SQL Bits vs Datetimes to determine the logical state of a record

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design

Hey everyone, I have this question that keeps coming up over and over in terms of best practices.

Lets say I have the following table:

```
[Process]
----------------
ProcessID int
ProcessName varchar(100)
...
```

In addition to the fields above, lets say a `[Process]` can have various states. It can be currently successful, currently unsuccessful, or neither. Theoretically it could be both but we won't worry about that. We also need to know WHEN this state was last updated.

My question is what is the best way to represent this state in the data-structure? I can think of a few possibilities:

(1) Add a column called `State (bit, null)` that is `1` for successful, `0` for unsuccessful, and `NULL` for neither. We then add a column `LastStateChangeDateTime (datetime, null)` that tells us when the `State` bit was last changed. I've never been given a straight answer as to whether this type of use of a bit is a bad idea.

(2) We add two columns called `HasState (bit, not null)` and `CurrentState (bit, not null)` and again our `LastStateChangeDateTime (datetime, null)` column. This takes away the "tri-state" use of a bit but seems clunky and confusing.

(3) We have two pairs of columns `IsCurrentlySuccessful (bit, not null)` and `SuccessBeginDateTime (datetime, null)` along with `IsCurrentlyFailing (bit, not null)` and `FailureBeginDateTime (datetime, null)`. This makes the two states independent of each other.

(4) No bits, only datetimes: `SuccessBeginDateTime (datetime, null)` and `FailureBeginDateTime (datetime, null)`. We infer state based on the datetime's themselves. I feel like this will lead to inefficient queries and/or indexes.

I know the above example is contrived, but does anyone have any good solutions as to how to handle this little data-structure problem effectively? Remember that in practice, these "States" are not necessarily mutually exclusive, so it wouldn't be the end of the world if the data-structure allowed for both states at once.

Thank you!

Comment: depends on what you really need/want to store and what you really need to return from a query and how you will search this data.

Comment: The performance critical queries are really just going to want to get all Processes that are successful (or not) regardless of when that state came into being; the datetime values are more for auxillary information. I would want to be able index on the "state" itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for option 4, unless your tables are huge and you would be concerned by performance. For me the other options show some level of "transitive dependency", and therefore pose a risk on data consistency.

Comment: There would be situations where I am concerned about performance; I see what you are saying about transitive dependency though. I guess I'm trying to find a middle ground between performance and data independence.